# Are $A=[0,1]\times[0,1]$ and $B=([0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q})\times([0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q})$ compact in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, compactness

$ A= \{ (x_1,x_2): x_1,x_2 \in [0,1] \} $ in $\mathbb{R}^2$

$ B= \{ (x_1,x_2): x_1,x_2 \in [0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q} \} $ in $\mathbb{R}^2$

I am using the usual Euclidean metric in $\mathbb{R}^2$. So, a set is compact iff its closed and bounded.

I have some issues to understand if those sets are compact. Do you have a good explanation?

Comment: What's your definition of closed? What's your definition of bounded? Or are you looking for an intuitive answer?

Comment: I'd also throw in that the definition of compactness is that every open cover has a finite subcover...It's true that this is equivalent to being closed and bounded, but only in metric spaces.

Comment: Ask yourself: is A closed? Is A bounded? And the same for B.

Comment: I gave some hints below. We are much more able to help you if you tell us how much you understand in the question statement, though. (For instance what definitions are you using, what is your reference, etc.)

Comment: just started to learn Topology..so im Aware of all the Standard definitions and sentences...but i am more asking for an intuitive answere...@Antonios-AlexandrosRobotis..thank you for your hints! I have to think about it.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT(S):** $A$ can be rewritten as $[0,1]\times[0,1]$. Is this set bounded? Is it true that $[0,1]\times[0,1]\subset B_{10}(0)?$ Here $B_r(p)$ is the ball of radius $r$ about $p\in \mathbf{R}^2$.

Is $A$ it closed? Is $A^C=\mathbf{R}^2\setminus [0,1]\times[0,1]$ open? Around any point in $A^C$ can you find a ball of radius $r>0$ contained in $A^C$? If so, $A^C$ is open and $A$ is closed.

$B$ can be rewritten as $([0,1]\cap \mathbf{Q})\times ([0,1]\cap \mathbf{Q}).$ Is $\mathbf{Q}$ closed in $\mathbf{R}?$ Is the limit of a convergent sequence of rationals rational? By the same reasoning, we can determine whether or not $[0,1]\cap \mathbf{Q}$ is closed in $[0,1]$.

To finish the problem, if we fix a rational point $p\in [0,1]\cap \mathbf{Q}$ and consider sequences 
$$ (p,q_n)_{n\in \mathbf{N}}\in B$$
then we are back to the $1-$dimensional case.

Answer (score 1):

$[0,1]^2$ is compact because you can prove that the Cartesian product of compact sets is compact if and only if their components are compact. We know $[0,1]$ is compact. (I am assuming the underlying topology is the standard one).

Note that  $[0,1]\cap \mathbb{Q}$  is not compact, since $\mathbb{Q}$ isn't even closed. To see this, take the sequence $\{x_n\}=\{\frac{1}{4}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n\}$. This sequence certainly contains only rationals in the unit interval, but $x_n \rightarrow \frac{e}{4}$, which is irrational, so we have shown $[0,1]\cap \mathbb{Q}$ is not even closed, so it cannot be compact (again, under standard topology). Since this set is not compact,

$B=([0,1]\cap \mathbb{Q})^2$ is not compact.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ is sequentially compact since $[0,1]$ is compact and for any sequence  $\{(x_n,y_n)\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ on $\mathbb{R^2}$ converges to $(K,L)$ iff  $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges to $K$ and $\{y_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges to $L$.

It's clear that $\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$ is not sequentially compact since there exists irrationals $q\in\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$ and we can construct a sequence on $\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$ that converges to $q$.

> **Example** : Consider the sequence $\{\frac{F_n}{F_{n+1}}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ where $F_n$ is the $n$ th
> Fibonacci number. This is a sequence on $\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$ that
> converges to $\frac1\varphi$ where $\varphi\in\mathbb{R-Q}$ is the
> golden ratio.

Therefore, if $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence on $\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$ that converges to a irrational, then $\{(0,x_n)\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence on $\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]\times\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$ that converges to a point in $\mathbb{R^2-Q^2}$. Hence $\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]\times\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$ is not compact.